# How a lambda can use an API gateway in a different stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm using AWS SAM and I have one problem.

I have one API Gateway resource that is in stack 1 and I have a lambda function in stack 2. I need to reference the API Gateway to create an event to fire. Cloudformation does not allow you to reference an API Gateway in another stack.

How can I solve this problem

Comment: Stacks can have outputs. Make the API Gateway URL an output from the 1st stack and then reference it in the 2nd stack. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686580/how-to-get-stack-output-from-aws-sam).

Comment: Here is the my lambda example

test:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: admin.set
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      MemorySize: 1024
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HttpEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /test
            Method: POST
            RestApiId: <api gateway resource>

In Lambda event RestApiId value must be resource defined in the same stack. Output value return string.

Comment: I have this error when use reference 

Event with id [HttpEvent] is invalid. RestApiId must be a valid reference to an 'AWS::Serverless::Api' resource in same template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to reference API resource defined in another template. Decided to create separate API's and use Custom Domain Names to have 1 endpoint

Comment: Hi @cWerning -- Can you please point where you answered? I am looking for solution to similar problem. Thank you.